# What is the correct format/resolutoin for videos on an HTC Wildfire?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, video, htc-wildfire

i currently own a HTC Wildfire. I am well aware of its "lower" CPU speed than its HTC brothers, nevertheless, it is a great phone and I'm very happy with it.

I tried putting a mp4/m4p video (around 330mb) and the built-in video player crashed.

Can anyone guide me on the correct format/resolution I can use on this phone? Additionally, if I do have to convert an existing video, what software do I use?

I appreciate all inputs, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, haven't updated this in a while. Since i was only using the free 2GB MicroSD bundled with the phone, this was causing the problem. so I purchased a 16GB, this fixed the issue. thanks!

Comment: Your new card probably has a better data transfer rate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [VPlayer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/vplayer-alpha/me.abitno.vplayer)?  It should handle any mp4, avi, divx, etc. video that you throw at it, without the need of converting it.